# What is miterLimit work or effect in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I looked some links to find out the result or effect of miterLimit on the Shape, there is some option possible to chose, but nothing happens, I need to learn how can I take advantage of miterLimit in full power mode and with explaining.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .stroke(.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5, lineJoin: .round, miterLimit: .pi))
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://swiftontap.com/strokestyle/miterlimit

Comment: @aheze: Thanks, LoL, that was one of the links I looked, but in SwiftUI we got some more options for miterLimit like `.pi` or even others, I need to know or see the effect, I played with it but it does nothing! :( I do not know what are the results of others tho.

Comment: `.pi` isn't a special option -- it's just a `CGFloat` equal to `3.14.....`

Comment: It is about results and output. I want be able see the deference.

Answer (score 1):

The site that @aheze linked to has some useful examples.

Here's one, similar to what's included in [Swift on Tap](https://swiftontap.com/strokestyle/miterlimit) where you can clearly see the difference:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .stroke(.red, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 50, lineJoin: .miter, miterLimit: 1))
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
}
```

When miterLimit is set to 1:
[image]

And when it's set to 10:
[image]

Their description of `miterLimit`:

> ... miter limit is the maximum ratio of the miter length to stroke width.

Note that `lineJoin` logically looks like it has to be set to `.miter` for the `miterLimit` to have an effect.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use your answer, for me it is same as links, before asking my question, as I mentioned in my question I need explain about each enum of miterLimit and a use case. By the way I had no issue given a random value to miterLimit to testing it before asking. I am looking explain for each case of enum with possible example of test code.

Comment: miterLimit doesn’t take an enum — it takes a CGFloat. “Each case” doesn’t make sense because there are a basically infinite number of values.

Comment: Oh yes, I was meaning about statics not enums, my bad. :) ok now I got to know my issue, why would for 10 be nothing in up but for 1 some result?

Comment: The link has an explanation of this: "miterLimit is "the limit on the ratio of the miter length to stroke width" and later "Once we know the miter length, we can figure out what the maximum possible miter limit. Recall, miter limit is the maximum ratio of the miter length to stroke width. So if we pass in a miter limit greater than the square root of 2, we should get normal miters. And if we we pass in a miter limit less than the square root of 2, we should get "limited" miters:"

Comment: @ioscoder is there something else I can add to make this answer acceptable?